# SimpleXML How to Transform this in android code?

Tags: retrofit2, simple-framework

```
@Root
public class DataSet {

    @Namespace()
    @Path("")
    private String WordKey;

    private String Pron;

    private String Orig;

    private String Trans;
}
```

I want use `retrofit2` with `simplexml` to transform http request. It's **android** code. I have trouble with transform xml. How to transform this ? How can i write the class ?

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://WebXml.com.cn/">
    <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="Dictionary">...</xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
        <Dictionary xmlns="">
            <Trans diffgr:id="Trans1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <WordKey>hello</WordKey>
                <Pron>'heləu, he'ləu</Pron>
                <Info/> 
                <Translation>int.（见面打招呼或打电话用语）喂,哈罗</Translation>
                <Mp3>1059.mp3</Mp3>
            </Trans>
            <Sentence diffgr:id="Sentence1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <Orig>
                    She actually condescended to say hello to me in the street today.
                </Orig>
                <Trans>她今天在街上竟能屈尊跟我打招呼.</Trans>
            </Sentence>
            <Sentence diffgr:id="Sentence2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                <Orig>
                    I said hello to her, but she ignored me completely!
                </Orig>
                <Trans>我向她打招呼, 可她根本不理我!</Trans>
            </Sentence>
            <Sentence diffgr:id="Sentence3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
                <Orig>Hello there, what a coincidence!</Orig>
                <Trans>你好，真巧啊!</Trans>
            </Sentence>
        </Dictionary>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Comment: Tagging to get the answer when responded by community. @TomDuan, Did you get the answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution by skipping `xs:schema` and `diffgr:diffgram` like this:

```
@Root(name = "DataSet", strict = false)
@Namespace(reference = "http://WebXml.com.cn/")
public class DataSet {

    @Path("diffgr:diffgram[1]")
    @Element(name = "Dictionary", required = false)
    private Dictionary dictionary;

}
```